# Using desktop as a clear white board

Tags: java, swing

Some software uses the monitor as a clear white board to draw. The white board is transparent, and you can see the desktop underneath the clear white board

So how this is possible?

I mean in Java is it like making the JFrame to screen size and making it transparent to draw or how is this being done?

We have a similar requirement so we're trying to understand how to do this?

Comment: Use C++ to create a layered window.

Comment: The keywords to search for: undecorated JFrame, setOpaque(false) (transparency), Robot. Take a demo paint program, with a MouseAdapter/MouseListener to track the drawing, and store them somehow. With Robot you can take a screenshot first.

Comment: This depends on the specific whiteboard program.

Comment: This is a different application, but take a look at this Java article, JCropFrame, to see how to make a transparent JFrame, use Robot to take a picture of the desktop, and act on the picture.  http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=76

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way to do it: you create a transparent window on which you put a `JLabel` displaying a `BufferedImage`. As the users presses and drags the mouse, you draw on the BufferedImage and repaint the label to update the content.

Some example code to get started:

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestTransparentFrame extends JLabel {

    private boolean drawing = false;
    private Point lastPoint;

    private BufferedImage image;

    public TestTransparentFrame() {
        addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                updateImage();
            }
        });
        MouseAdapter mouseAdapter = new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                drawing = true;
                lastPoint = e.getPoint();
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                drawing = false;
                lastPoint = null;
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                drawing = false;
                lastPoint = null;
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                if (drawing && lastPoint != null) {
                    Graphics graphics = image.getGraphics();
                    graphics.setColor(Color.RED);
                    ((Graphics2D) graphics).setStroke(new BasicStroke(5.0f));
                    graphics.drawLine(lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y, e.getX(), e.getY());
                    repaint();
                    lastPoint = e.getPoint();
                }
            }
        };
        addMouseListener(mouseAdapter);
        addMouseMotionListener(mouseAdapter);
    }

    protected void updateImage() {
        if (image == null || image.getWidth() < getWidth() || image.getHeight() < getHeight()) {
            if (image == null) {
                image = getGraphicsConfiguration().createCompatibleImage(getWidth(), getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            } else {
                BufferedImage newImage = getGraphicsConfiguration().createCompatibleImage(getWidth(), getHeight(),
                        BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
                newImage.getGraphics().drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
                image = newImage;
            }
        } else {
            image = image.getSubimage(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        }
        setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
    }

    protected void initUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(TestTransparentFrame.class.getSimpleName());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255, 1));
        TestTransparentFrame comp = new TestTransparentFrame();
        frame.setContentPane(comp);
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestTransparentFrame().initUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

And the result:

[image]

Comment: ya something like this. I will try this and let you know if i find any better solution than this. Thank u so much.